how do i create and append to a new dataframe utilizing a iteration loop to extract of data?
i want to have a basic direct method to use different  criteria to form new dataframes which i will display in a simple pie chart. i have such a feeble grasp of the topic that it seems to be difficult but there's got to be some pretty basic methods of which i am unawares of.
essentially i want to isolate ranges of data... example, a set of 100 datapoints. perhaps the 100 most common values or the 100 lowest values or the 100 highest values.. .
for i in range(100):
    global my_pie
    my_pie = pd.DataFrame(data.iloc[[i],[1,3]])
    

display(my_pie)

so here i have this failed code as it only assigns the last iteration to the dataframe "my_pie"
i wanted a dataframe that had 100 rows for the iloc columns 1 and 3 of the "data" dataframe.
i want to understand the fundamentals of assigning different criteria for new dataframes from which i wish to display. the simple syntax is elusive to me.

Your question is not very clear to me. Do you want to know how to filter your dataframe based on different conditions on rows and columns?

i wanted to have a dataframe of 100 rows as opposed to just 1 row of the last iteration of my for loop.

well you don't even need a loop. Try this: df = data.iloc[:100, [1, 3]]

that sounds about right..  and if i wanted to add or append lets say one more row to df, how does it work? i see the question asked all the time but the answers seem overly complex.  how do i get the 100 you have plus one more?  data.iloc[[101], [1,3]] yes,. your code worked perfectly. so how do i add additional entry. i don't want to re-invoke the initial 100 entries, i want to dynamically add to it.

Are you selecting from an existing dataframe or are you trying to create new entries?

Ok let's say you want to take the 101st row from data and append it to the df. you can use this: pd.concat([df, data.iloc[[101], [1, 3]]], ignore_index=True)

thank you sir. seems to be the solution i was looking for. merge append add and concat had me in a tailspin.. i believe your solution is the the desired understanding i was looking for.  very good

It's a little unclear what you are asking, but from what I understand it sounds like you need to do more research on the iloc metohd. It can index in a variety of different ways. To get your result, I would try
my_pie = data.iloc[:100, 1:3]


yes the question is vague; what you want, have you consult the panda's docs, do you know how it works
df.loc 

A better solution is to append those rows to a list and then concatenate the list with the original DataFrame.
check out the given link for the docs, what i get from your question would help you.enter link description here
